# Getting HTTP/0.0 307 Temporary Redirect in connecting to my vps without typing https://

Tags: networking, server, dns, ssl, tls

I ran a graphical version of v2ray([X-UI](https://seakfind.github.io/2021/10/10/X-UI/)) on one of my VPS on Hetzner, I also add an `A` record to bind the IP of this VPS to a DNS on my Cloudflare account.

Well with the below commands, I tried to get a certificate for this subdomain with `acme.sh` and using letsencrypt as CA provider:

```sh
    7  curl https://get.acme.sh | sh
    8  ~/.acme.sh/acme.sh --set-default-ca --server letsencrypt
    9  ~/.acme.sh/acme.sh --register-account -m myemail@mailserver.com
   10  ~/.acme.sh/acme.sh --issue -d sub.mydns.com --standalone
   11  ~/.acme.sh/acme.sh --installcert -d sub.mydns.com --key-file /root/private.key --fullchain-file /root/cert.crt
```

After adding the IP address of VPS to Cloudflare and setting it in DNS-only mode like the below image:

[image]

When I try to connect my panel without typing the `https://`, I've just got the below page from Firefox:

[image]

And also return nothing in the Google Chrome browser(with or without typing `https://`):

[image]

But typing `https://` shows me the panel successfully:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and how I can fix this?

Comment: If you’re using CloudFlare there is no need to create your own SSL certificates, as they can do that for you. There is also a setting in the CloudFlare options to auto-redirect all non-HTTPS web traffic so that you do not need to configure it on the web server. These two options will save you time and hassle.

Comment: Are the SSL certificates provided by Cloudflare free?Can I setup a vless config via tls with these SSL certificates?